# How to use fewer markers while keeping curve details?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to add a few markers to a curve with lots of points, like shown below, but without resorting to the second **addplot**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[color=red,no markers] coordinates {
    (2,-1.8559703)
    (2.5,-2.8559703)
    (3,-3.5301677)
    (3.5,-4.01677)
    (4,-4.3050655)
    (4.5,-4.813136)
    (5,-5.1413136)
    (5.5,-5.7322865)
    (6,-6.0322865)
    (6.5,-6.675052)
    (7,-6.9675052)
    (7.5,-7.975052)
    (8,-8.9377747)
  };
  \addplot[color=red, only marks] coordinates {
    (2,-1.8559703)
    (4,-4.3050655)
    (6,-6.0322865)
    (8,-8.9377747)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have several keys allowing to control which markers should be drawn:

1. You can use `mark repeat=<number>`; this allows to draw only each `nth` mark where `n` was the value provided as `<number>`.
2. `mark phase=<number>`; add this after using `mark repeat` to control the starting point for the markers.
3. There also `mark indices={<index list>}`; use this to specify the index list of markers that should be drawn.

A complete example showing those keys in action (the first example gives the marking schema you requested in your question):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot+[color=red,mark repeat=4] coordinates {
    (2,-1.8559703)
    (2.5,-2.8559703)
    (3,-3.5301677)
    (3.5,-4.01677)
    (4,-4.3050655)
    (4.5,-4.813136)
    (5,-5.1413136)
    (5.5,-5.7322865)
    (6,-6.0322865)
    (6.5,-6.675052)
    (7,-6.9675052)
    (7.5,-7.975052)
    (8,-8.9377747)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot+[color=red,mark repeat=3,mark phase=2] coordinates {
    (2,-1.8559703)
    (2.5,-2.8559703)
    (3,-3.5301677)
    (3.5,-4.01677)
    (4,-4.3050655)
    (4.5,-4.813136)
    (5,-5.1413136)
    (5.5,-5.7322865)
    (6,-6.0322865)
    (6.5,-6.675052)
    (7,-6.9675052)
    (7.5,-7.975052)
    (8,-8.9377747)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot+[color=red,mark indices={1,5,9}] coordinates {
    (2,-1.8559703)
    (2.5,-2.8559703)
    (3,-3.5301677)
    (3.5,-4.01677)
    (4,-4.3050655)
    (4.5,-4.813136)
    (5,-5.1413136)
    (5.5,-5.7322865)
    (6,-6.0322865)
    (6.5,-6.675052)
    (7,-6.9675052)
    (7.5,-7.975052)
    (8,-8.9377747)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]